# asp.net mvc, EF with memorycache high memory usage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, memory, nopcommerce, objectcache

We have an asp.net MVC website(nopcommerce 3.6) (**Site 1**) using Entity framework and inmemorycache. The memory consumption of the site is very high. Reaches to ~14gb.
The application sits in a windows 2008 server with 16gb of RAM.

I need help in understanding the following scenarios/behavior:

The application does not *seem to* release memory when no other application is currently in use in the server. It uses the maximum memory.

However, if i launch **another asp.net application** (**Site 2**)and push it to consume some memory, **site 1** release its memory(drops drastically) and both these applications start sharing the RAM.

**Is this an acceptable behavior** and what happens when my RAM gets to 100% and only one website is running?

When will my site 1 release its memory automatically? Will GC kick in only if my RAM gets to 100%?

Do i have a memory leak? If so, how does it release memory when **site 2** needs it?

Note: we cache the EF objects(using inmemory objectcache) with proxy and tracking enabled.
And yes dotmemory is my next option.

Comment: put here a sample of your caching approach please.

Comment: i would recomend you should upgrade the site to version 3.90 since they made alot of changes to handle memory issues, and test if it still happens. for more look here http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/45428/reducing-the-memory-usage-on-startup.aspx